# Configuring php on Ubuntu server

Tags: apache2, php

I have been following this tutorial

http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp

And I have got to the part where I am running a simple test to determine whether php has been installed properly

the installation went fine, I installed php5 using the following command
`apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5` and I then restarted the server.

to see whether php5 has been installed I did the following

created a file `vi /var/www/info.php`

edited the file `<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

after trying to run it on my server I get a 404 Not Found error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try changing the permission of files under /var/www and check http://localhost/info.php

Comment: @devav2 Im not running the server on my computer I can't use local host, but I'll look into changing permissions

Comment: okay got you :)

Comment: If the apache place holder worked for you but the php info did not try `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Comment: Create the file info.php in /var/www/html/ instead of /var/www/.

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

First check your Ubuntu Version.

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
```

Restarting apache services will solved your problem.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are getting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Then your apache root directory will be /var/www/html/

```
 sudo vim /var/www/html/info.php
```

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

write your php script.

Restart apache2 service.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a permission problem it should return 403, not 404. Check the files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ . There is probably only one file (000-default) if you didn't create any new hostnames yourself. Does it say 'DocumentRoot /var/www' ? And does it say:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>`
```

Somewhere?